# Deprecation Warning: The selector ">" is invalid CSS. This will be an error in Dart Sass 2.0.0

Tags: css, reactjs, package.json, node-sass, dart-sass

I'm migrating from node-sass to dart-sass and in my .css file I have this style:

```
> .wc-card .wc-list.hero > .ac-container > .ac-container {
  width: 273px;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

When i build my react application with *npm install* I have this error:

**Deprecation Warning:** The selector "> .wc-card .wc-list.hero > .ac-container > div > div > div > button" is invalid CSS.
This will be an error in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

I have this version on my package.json:

```
   "sass": "^1.49.9",
```

So my question is, how can i replace this operator? I am not a css/sass expert.

Comment: do you have a parent selector, which you've put before the child operator ‘>’? If not, try to specify it or remove the first ‘>’ — does it work this way?

Comment: yes indeed! The problem was a parent selector has a > and a & so compiled to css becomes like i writed in the question.